# Check if queue is empty using esql

Tags: middleware, messagebroker

I am writing a code to clear all the messages in the queue.
I am using a Compute and GET node for the purpose.
I want to loop through the messages while clearing each message and want the loop to stop when the queue is empty.

Please give me some suggestions for achieving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MQGet node has a no message output terminal, where the process routes in case there was no message on the queue.

So you could achieve your goal by connecting the Out terminal of the MQGet to the In terminal of your Compute node, and the No Message terminal of the MQGet to nothing or some other Compute if you want to do something more after getting all the messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I am trying to clear 10000 but it is removing only 94 messages..I checked in the event viewer and its showing stack overflow error..Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: You should provide some more info, at least the error message, but without the outline of your flow, and the esql code we can only guess on the cause.